# How to determine if page is within iFrame and redirect to different pages

Tags: javascript, vbscript, asp-classic

I currently have below logic to redirect to login page if session is expired:

```
if IsEmpty(Session("Something")) then response.redirect "login.asp"
```

I need to add to this condition to redirect to a separate page if our site is within an external iFrame. So I implemented the following logic:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function isSiteFramed() {
    if (window.top !== window.self) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I am unable to call this javascript function in my vbscript. I was advised not to do the redirection within the javascript function itself as if cross site scripting in URL is put, then the javascript function would not be executed and therefore, the login page would not be redirected.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

There is no option in VBScript to redirect another frame in the browser.

See this MSDN article [Manipulating Frames with VBScript and ASP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms952629.aspx)

> While ASP is great at building the individual pages for a web application dynamically, its features are rather limited when it comes to handling the frameset pages that are so common to today's sites. Using the Redirect method of the Response object we can redirect to a single page, but we can't target it to a specific frame—only the browser can do that.

I would also think that Server Side JScript would not be able to detect frames either.